# Cats With Hats - Challenge. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got the solutions for this problem but: I am struggling to see the logic behind the solutions! can someone please explain how it works?

You have 100 cats.
One day you decide to arrange all your cats in a giant circle. Initially, none of your cats have any hats on. You walk around the circle 100 times, always starting at the same spot, with the first cat (cat # 1). Every time you stop at a cat, you either put a hat on it if it doesn’t have one on, or you take its hat off if it has one on.

1. The first round, you stop at every cat, placing a hat on each one.
2. The second round, you only stop at every second cat (#2, #4, #6, #8, etc.).
3. The third round, you only stop at every third cat(#3,#6,#9,#12, etc.).
4. You continue this process until you’ve made 100 rounds around the cats (e.g., you only visit the 100th cat).

Write a program that simply outputs which cats have hats at the end.

Here are the solution 
Solution #1:

```
def get_cats_with_hats(array_of_cats):
    cats_with_hats_on = []

    for num in range(1, 100 + 1):
        for cat in range(1, 100 + 1):
            if cat % num == 0:
                if array_of_cats[cat] is True:
                    array_of_cats[cat] = False
                else:
                    array_of_cats[cat] = True
    for cat in range(1, 100 + 1):
        if cats[cat] is True:
            cats_with_hats_on.append(cat)
    return cats_with_hats_on


cats = [False] * (100 + 1)
print(get_cats_with_hats(cats))
```

---

Solution #2:

```
number_of_cats = 100
cats_with_hats = []
number_of_laps = 100

# We want the laps to be from 1 to 100 instead of 0 to 99
for lap in range(1, number_of_laps + 1):
    for cat in range(1, number_of_cats + 1):

        # Only look at cats that are divisible by the lap
        if cat % lap == 0:
            if cat in cats_with_hats:
                cats_with_hats.remove(cat)
            else:
                cats_with_hats.append(cat)

print(cats_with_hats)
```

Comment: Is there any part of the solutions that you do understand?  What in particular are you unsure about?

Comment: Just for fun here's a one liner solution.  `print([i for i in range(1, number_of_cats+1) if sum(1 for n in range(1, number_of_laps+1) if not i%n)%2])`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying hard coding . These solutions can be time consuming i mean not efficient for programming contest. 
First cat = true cuz circle start with this cat and never be the same spot
Second cat =false cuz circle will start second time in this spot 
After this you can know if you know divider of this cat 
**For example :** 8th cat 
dividers of 8 = 1,2,4,8 
8 th cat will be = false 
if dividers count %2 ==0 then it is false
else it is true

Can you share the link of problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a famous mathematical puzzle. The number of times the state of cat *c* is flipped is equal to how many distinct factors the number *c* has. For cat *c* to be wearing a hat at the end, it must have been flipped an odd number of times, meaning *c* must have an odd number of distinct factors.

Factors come in pairs, e.g. 12 = 2 × 6 so the factor 2 is paired with the factor 6. The only way *c* can have an odd number of factors is if some factor *f* is paired with itself, i.e. *c* = *f* × *f*. That is, cat *c* ends up wearing a hat if and only if *c* is a square number. So, we just have to output a list of the square numbers in the range.

```py
def get_cats_with_hats():
    return [i*i for i in range(1, 11)]
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the full problem, as the described problem has 2 parameters (cats and laps).  It should be pointed out that this explanation relies on `cats<=laps`

Comment: @HymnsForDisco The described **problem** does not have two parameters; it has no parameters at all: *"You have 100 cats ... You walk around the circle 100 times"*. The second **solution** in the OP's question has those two parameters, but if the OP is interested in that generalisation of the problem then they should have said so.

Comment: The asker very broadly asked for help in understanding.  I believe the assumption should be explicitly noted regardless, as it otherwise it may not be immediately obvious that this logic would no longer apply for say, 100 cats and 10 laps.

Comment: Well, you have explicitly noted it in your comment, but I do not think it needs to be explicitly noted because there is nothing in the *description* of the problem which suggests, if the problem should be generalised, that the number of cats and the number of laps might not be equal. I think it is usually wrong to infer additional unstated assumptions about the problem based on a presented solution, especially when *two* solutions are presented and only one of them suggests the additional unstated assumption. For all we know, solution #2 has two separate variables purely for readability.

Comment: I believe that potential generalization is implicit in nearly every conversation about programming, and certainly ones about algorithms.  Identifying and eliminating magic numbers is an important habit for any programmer to learn.  Of course we are here to answer questions, but it doesn't hurt to pass along some if these values where applicable, especially for newer users

Comment: The natural generalisation would be to let n be the number of cats and the number of laps. Generalisation is obviously important in programming, and if a generalisation of a problem has substantially the same solution then it doesn't hurt to include the generalisation in a discussion of the original problem. But if the generalisation requires a substantially different solution (not just naming a parameter), and there's no indication that the generalisation is actually required, then what you are talking about is called "premature generalisation". It can be as harmful as premature optimisation.

Comment: My original concern was not with how the generalization may necessitate change of the code, but how it would necessitate changing the understanding of the problem as it is explained in your answer.  The second sentence is a fact that comes as a result of a few different aspects of the problem working together, but those aspects and relationships are not identified, and so the understanding is not as strong or adaptable as it could be